# AWS Capacity Provider for ECS cluster not triggering scale-in event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have added a Capacity Provider to an ECS cluster. While scale-out events work as expected due to changes in `CapacityProviderReservation` metric, scale-in events do not work.

In my case, the `TargetCapacity` property is set to `90`, but looking at CloudWatch the average for the `CapacityProviderReservation` metric currently sits at 50%. This has been the case for the last 16 hours.

According to [AWS's own documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#common-scenarios-termination-scale-in), scale-in events occur -

> When using dynamic scaling policies and the size of the group decreases as a result of changes in a metric's value

So it seems like the Capacity Provider is not changing the desired size of the ASG as expected.

Am I missing something here, or do capacity providers tied to ASG's simply not work both ways?

##### ASG and Capacity Provider resources in CloudFormation

```
Resources:
  AutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: !Sub ${ResourceNamePrefix}-asg
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnetAId
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref Ec2LaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt Ec2LaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      MinSize: 0
      MaxSize: 3
      DesiredCapacity: 1

  EcsCapacityProvider:
    Type: AWS::ECS::CapacityProvider
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${ResourceNamePrefix}-ecs-capacity-provider
      AutoScalingGroupProvider:
        AutoScalingGroupArn: !Ref AutoScalingGroup
        ManagedScaling:
          Status: ENABLED
          TargetCapacity: 90
        ManagedTerminationProtection: DISABLED
```

##### Dynamic scaling policy for ASG

[image]

##### Current status of the `CapacityProviderReservation` metric

The `CapacityProviderReservation` metric has been at 50% for well over 12 hours.

[image]

##### Current status of the Capacity Provider

As you can see, the desired size is still `2`, while it is expected that this should have dropped back to `1`.

[image]

## Update

After deleting and recreating the cluster, I notice that the Capacity Provider changes the `DesiredCapacity` to 2 instantly, even though there are no tasks running.